# Dependency injection in IValueConverter MVVM Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-injection, prism

I Want to pass Dependency injection in IValueConverter in MVVM (Prism).

I used ServiceLocator, but it not working with .Net Core 3.1.

please let me if any way to do Dependency injection in IValueConverter.

```
public class RowToColorConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    private ICommonInventoryReference _commonInventoryReference;

    /// <summary>
    /// back Event Args Converter
    /// </summary>
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {

        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (_commonInventoryReference == null)
        {
            _commonInventoryReference = null;
        } // CommonServiceLocator.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CommonInventoryReference>(); }

        if (_commonInventoryReference == null || !(value is Inventory inventory)) { return Brushes.White; }

        var brand = _commonInventoryReference.LoadBrandsByIdOrName(new BrandModel() { Name = inventory.Brand });
        if (brand == null || string.Compare(brand.IsBrand, "YES", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
        {
            return Brushes.White;
        }
        var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#edecbb");
        return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(color.A, color.R, color.G, color.B));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ContainerLocator` instead, as seen in the relase notes.